# How to convert % to decimal in excel/ Libre Office Calc formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

1. I am having trouble to calculate the compounding trade lot size as it should multiply the keyed value such as 0.01 x the % gain entered. But if I put 100% gain and do starting value*100% value it makes 0.01 turn to 1.01 which is wrong it should be 0.02. Hope someone can help me!
2. How can I have the formula round the figure down to 100? See row 23 onwards it must be rounded to 100 as this is the lot size limit.

See the spreadsheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uvt9efqMC_XZvxCw3h7zqISxm-S3MhVNY0OBv3QReKI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Treat percentages like decimals. Move the decimal point 2 places to the left, so 100% == 1.00, 47.5% == 0.475 etc. Then `value = value + (value*decimal)` [I've no idea how you would want to implement that in your sheet, so not posting as an answer]

Answer (score 0):

1. When you look for

> put 100% gain

it should mean : multiply by (1 + 100%), which is also (1 + 1).
So your expected formula should be: `<keyed value> * (1 + <pct gain>)`, as in : `0.01 * (1 + 100%) = 0.02`

Would you have `100` in your cell when you type `100%`, then it is due to your cell formatting. It may take into account `%`, then just enter `1`.

2. You can cap with `=min(<max value>, <your formula to limit>)`, aka `=min(100, 111) = 100`

PS, I believe your formulas use commas `,` as separator, though it may be semicolon `;` - depending on your geographical region configuration

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello. Thank you! I tried to put what you gave me with my forula and got parse error. or FALSE. Can you please check and try? I used: =min(100,C10/K8) = 100 for E 10. 
Editor access link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uvt9efqMC_XZvxCw3h7zqISxm-S3MhVNY0OBv3QReKI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It seems to put true if i put max and it should limit the number not write text true or false. I want the number to round down to the max lots value (100).

Comment: I tried your formula, it seem to work. Also double checked on cell `F37`.

When you use `max()`, you ask for the highest value fed to be kept, so `max(100;0,01)` = `100`

Comment: the max formula worked great for the profit and lot size both thank you. Can you please now help me with the profit share cells and the formulas associated with those? If not it's fine just thought I'd ask.

Comment: Please update your question, or ask a new one, explaining how you tried to apply the formula for profit share (cf. [formula](https://savvycalculator.com/profit-sharing-ratio-calculator/)), so users understand the reply.